# Update na tabela de estoque

Tags: php, mysql

**Tenho três tabelas:**

1- RegEntradaNutricia com os seguintes campos: *DataEntrada, CodFornecedor, DescricaoProd, Quantidade, Preco.*

2- RegSaidaNutricia com os seguintes campos: *DataSaida, DescricaoProd, Quantidade.*

3- StockNutricia com os seguintes campos: *ProdNutricia, Quantidade*.

Gostaria de ao inserir do formulário para a tabela *RegEntradaNutricia,* que me somasse a quantidade desse formulário à quantidade da tabela *StockNutricia* para controlar o estoque.

E quando inserir de outro formulário para a tabela *RegSaidaNutricia*, que me retirasse a quantidade desse formulário à quantidade da tabela *StockNutricia*.

**Isto é o código e o formulário que tenho:**

```
<?php 
$servername = "xxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8');

$data = $_POST['DataEntrada'];
$fornecedor = $_POST['CodFornecedor'];
$descricao = $_POST['DescricaoProd']; 
$quantidade = $_POST['Quantidade'];
$preco = $_POST['Preco'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO RegEntradaNutricia (`DataEntrada`,`CodFornecedor`,`DescricaoProd`,`Quantidade`,`Preco`)
VALUES ('$data','$fornecedor','$descricao','$quantidade','$preco')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE);

$rowCount = $query->num_rows;

$conn->close();
 ?>
```

```html
 <form name="form1" method="POST" onsubmit="return form_validation()" >

<h1><center><strong>Entrada de Produtos Nutricia</strong></center></h1></br>

<p><h5><strong>Data Entrada</strong></h5> <input type="date" required="" id="DataEntrada" name="DataEntrada" /><br/></p>
<p><h5><strong>Código Fornecedor</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="CodFornecedor" name="CodFornecedor" required="" size="120" /><br/></p>
<label for=""><h5><strong>Produto</strong></h5></label>
<select name="DescricaoProd">
       <option value="0">Selecione Produto</option>
        <?php
         $servername = "xxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxx";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset('utf8'); 
        
         $sql = "SELECT * FROM ProdNutricia ORDER BY ProdNutricia ASC";
         $qr = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
         while($ln = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qr)){
            echo '<option value="'.$ln['ProdNutricia'].'">'.$ln['ProdNutricia'].'</option>';
         }
      ?>        
    </select>
<p><h5><strong>Quantidade</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Quantidade" name="Quantidade" required="" size="120" /><br/></p> 
<p><h5><strong>Preço</strong></h5> <input type="text" id="Preco" name="Preco" required="" size="120" /><br/></p> 

<input type="submit" value="Registar"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Como essas tabelas se relacionam? não deveria existir um "IDProduto" ou "CodProduto" nas três tabelas?

Comment: Podemos relacionar pelo nome do produto, porque é sempre escrito da mesma forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode colocar o `UPDATE` no seu php após o `INSERT` executado, exemplo:

Após o INSERT na tabela **RegEntradaNutricia**:

```
$sql = "UPDATE StockNutricia SET Quantidade = Quantidade +" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockNutricia.ProdNutricia =" . $descricao
```

Após o INSERT na tabela **RegSaidaNutricia**:

```
$sql = "UPDATE StockNutricia SET Quantidade = Quantidade -" . $quantidade . " WHERE StockNutricia.ProdNutricia =" . $descricao
```

**Importante:**

Notei que o relacionamento ocorre pela descrição, o ideal é que exista uma forma de indentificação única, um `IDProduto` por exemplo. Isso envolve a modelagem do seu banco e seria assunto para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Ainda não testei, mas agradeço a ajuda e mal possa vou testar. Só uma questão, nas tabelas RegEntradaNutricia e RegSaidaNutricia não têm idprod porque são preenchidas pelo formulário, como coloco de forma automática para ser inserido o idprod da tabela ProdNutricia  que é onde ficam registados todos os produtos nas tabelas onde os formulários inserem os dados.

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta, espero que te ajude. Para você utilizar um IDProduto por exemplo vai depender de como está modelado seu banco de dados agora e pode ter um impacto grande caso faça isso e  tenha dúvidas sugiro a criação de uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela dica.....funcionou....só tive de acrescentar mais uma coisa ao código, mas a tua ajuda foi essencial......também já resolvi a situação do relacionamento por identificação única......obrigado